# How to embed database derby in jar file

Tags: java, derby

I do not want to install a database server on target machine. It is possible  that we can simply ship a jar file with the database embedded in it, and not worry about installing a database server separately?
I created one application in netbeans using derby and it is working fine in my pc but when i am running on other machine it is giving me  `Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 --> this error says that there is no Database running on port 1527.`   but i dont want that the client should take more efforts to start DB server and all technical process. It should be simply runnable when i start application Derby DB should start and when i close DB should close.
So what will be the solution for my problem?
And one more Question is Can i use derby database for large scale projects?

Comment: It is very hard to use DERBY for production.My offer is use mysql :)

Comment: HSQL is lightweight database server and you can embed the server in your application. You can do start/stop programatically.

Comment: Note that if the client and server are on different machines, the JDBC Connection URL must not specify "localhost". You'll have to get the correct network name for the clients to use to connect to that server machine, and you'll have to ensure that firewalls, etc. allow the clients to make that connection. Note also that the server is a separate process on a separate machine, and it isn't automatically started or stopped; you'll have to configure your operating system if you need the Network Server automatically started and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to install a database server on the target machine; Derby works just fine in embedded mode without a separate server.

However, if you want multiple client applications to be actively sharing the same data in the same database, you'll want to use the client-server mode, not the embedded mode.

And yes you can embed a jar with the database into your program. If you want to know how, read this documentation: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlp24155.html

And yes you can use Derby for large scale projects. But it doesn't come with all the enterprise features (online backup, etc.) that a true enterprise scale commercial DBMS comes with.

But, since it sounds like you are just getting started with Derby, can I suggest that you please start with the Derby tutorials before you try these advanced configurations? Here is the link to the Derby tutorials: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/

It may not be possible to give you very good advice without knowing a lot more about the application you're trying to build and the overall architecture you're trying to use.

Comment: I disagree with the implied statement that embedded Derby can be used for large projects. First of all, it is an understatement that it scales horribly. Second, taking backups is cumbersome at best. And last but not least remote access, mandatory for 3 tier architectures is simply impossible.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of unsuccessful ways to use Derby, too. I'm sorry you wandered into some of those. Perhaps you would like some help? But of course, if you don't want to use Derby, nobody is forcing you to.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: Derby is an *awesome* tool. I use it for integration tests all the time and I use it for smaller projects and as a fallback database. It has proven itself way, way more often than not. But for large projects (multiple tiers/multiple machines), embedded Derby is not the best choice as detailed above.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton thanks a lot for the link i read this. but i am not understanding how to configure in other machine. do you have any video link or code sample that help me for understading.

Comment: In a client/server configuration, you run the Network Server on your server machine, and client applications on each of your client machines. They communicate using TCP/IP sockets. TCP/IP connectivity has to be available between the machines. The client machines must specify the right network address to the server (not "localhost"). Here's a good place to start: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/cadminov825266.html

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg very good points. I fully agree with the limitations and complications that you mention. In recent versions of Derby, you can combine both Network Server and Embedded mode into a "Embedded Server" configuration which is quite interesting, though still more complicated to set up and maintain.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Now that's interesting. Have to dig into that. Thanks for that and all your hard work!